# Different hyphenation pattern when using oldstyle figures?

Tags: fonts, spacing, hyphenation, oldstylenums, mathpazo

It appears that there are different hyphenation patters when using oldstyle figures or not. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\areaset[current]{336pt}{600pt}
\overfullrule=5pt

\usepackage{mathpazo}

%\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}

%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont[
%   Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional},
%       ]   {TeX Gyre Pagella}

\begin{document}
\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum
ut
\end{document}
```

Which generates an overfull hbox:
[image: Hyphenation with mathpazo]

If we activate old style figures, that problem does not occur: 
[image: Hyphenation with osf-mathpazo]

I have two questions:

1. What is going on here? I don't see any numbers in the text, so why would XeLaTeX generate different output?
2. Ultimately I want to use the Open Type Font TeX Gyre Pagella. If we generate this example the result is identical to the first picture, i.e. we get an overfull hbox. How can I achieve the same result as with osf-mathpazo?

Comment: I get essentially the same output with the simple `mathpazo` as well as with TeX Gyre Pagella. However the text font is not the same, so differences in character width and other aspects such as kerning can be expected.

Comment: @egreg: That the output between Pazo Math and TeX Gyre Pagella can be different is clear to me, but why is the output different when using mathpazo with or without old style fonts?

Comment: With option osf mathpazo uses the family pplj and so at the end (if you look in the fd-file) pplr9o. Without the option ppl/pplr7t is used. One would have to check the tfm-file to find out where they differ.

Comment: The abbreviation `OSF` usually stands for "oldstyle figures". Hence, please consider editing the title of your question to read "... oldstyle figures?" rather than "... old style fonts?. Old-style fonts tends to refer to fonts with "fancy" glyph shapes, such as a long-s -- a subject not intended to be brought up by your question, right?

Comment: Title edited. As @Mico suggested I am talking about oldstyle figures, not fonts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The different hyphenation patterns are caused by the more spacious kerning and word spacing of the `pplx` and `pplj` font families. Quoting [Using common PostScript fonts with LaTeX](ftp://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/psnfss/psnfss2e.pdf), p. 4 (emphasis added):

> By default, the package `mathpazo` uses the typeface family `ppl` as
>   the roman text font family. The option `[sc]` selects Palatino with
>   real smallcaps (family `pplx`) insread [sic!]. Correspondingly, the option
>   `[osf]` selects Palatino with smallcaps and default oldstyle figures
>   (family `pplj`). Of course, oldstyle figures will be used only in text
>   mode, as opposed to formulas. Using either option is strongly
>   recommended: Beside the real smallcaps, the font families `pplx` and
>   `pplj` show further improvements over `ppl`: *Increased word space,
>   enhanced kerning tables*, additional ‘dotlessj’ glyph.

Comment: So it's not a bug, it's a feature :-)! Can we "assume" that professional fonts such as Adobe Garamond Pro or Minion Pro have the "perfect" word spacing? Or is that something that can/should be improved for professional looking documents?

Comment: @Jörg You should assume that the kerning of professional fonts is already good, but that there's always room for improvement (especially for "obscure" letter pairs).

Comment: Sorry, I was actually referring to interword space, not kerning.

Comment: @Jörg: Interword spacing is somehat more a matter of taste, altough the default values of professional fonts should be sensible.

Answer (score 5):

The results are very similar when

```
\usepackage{mathpazo}
```

alone is used or

```
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
```

is specified. When only

```
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
```

is declared, the result is different, because the font, for reasons that I don't know, has rather different font space parameters. With `\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}` I get

> Interword space: 2.91pt
>   Interword stretch: 1.75pt
>   Interword shrink: 0.7pt

while, with `\usepackage{mathpazo}` the result is

> Interword space: 2.5pt
>   Interword stretch: 1.49998pt
>   Interword shrink: 0.59998pt

The larger interword space for Old Style Figures MathPaZo clearly accounts for the different result.

I got the table by the code

```
\noindent Interword space: \the\fontdimen2\font\\
Interword stretch: \the\fontdimen3\font\\
Interword shrink: \the\fontdimen4\font
```

issued after `\begin{document}`

Comment: Not being an expert in fonts at all, but that sounds like a bug. How do you measure the font space parameters?